# unable to get line breaks when sending mail via php mail() function

Tags: php, email

Here is my code:

```
        $body = "Name:{$name}".PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "Phone:".$phone.PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "Email:".$email."\n\n";
    $body .= "Comments:".$comments."\n\n";
    $headers = 'From: MAILER <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '. $email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"; 
    mail($emailTo, "New message", $body, $headers);
```

as you can see I've tried to use, \r\n\, \n\n, PHP_EOL etc...
the only way it works is when i removing my "content-type" header.
anyone have an idea for why is it like that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are sending HTML email you need to use `<br>`  to set the line breaks.  Well that or wrap everything in `<pre></pre>` tags to honor the \n.  IF you don't need HTML in the output just set your content to `'text/plain'`, and the line breaks would show up.

Since it isn't multi-part try adding `MIME-Version: 1.0` to the headers.  That might help with the content type.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
```

Comment: text/plain and \r\n as the line breaks should work. If you look at the raw message source do you see the line breaks and the content-type headers.

Comment: thats very odd. it doesn't work as you say, i even changed it again to text/html, and added <br> tags, but still dosent work. in the raw source it has line breaks, but not in the original message.

Comment: Just remove the content type then.. My guess is that since you not sending a multi-part email, the mail client is choking on it.  The content type really isn't needed unless you are sending MIME / Multi-part messages.

Comment: ok, but can i still leave the "Charset=utf-8" to stand by it self as a header?

Comment: I am going to edit my answer, but try adding the Mime Version that might help.

Answer (score 1):

use as explain in example

```
$toemail=$emailid;
                $subject="You have registered successfully , please activate your account.";
                $msgbody.='<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
                $msgbody.='<tr><td>Admin Approved your profile and the details are : </td></tr>';
                $msgbody.='<tr><td>Username : '.$username.'</td></tr>';
                $msgbody.='<tr><td>Email : '.$emailid.'</td></tr>';
                $msgbody.='<tr><td>Password : '.$_SESSION['fan_user_password'].'</td></tr>';
                $msgbody.='<tr><td><a href="'.BASE_URL.'activate/fan/'.$lastid.'/'.$activation_code.'">';
                $msgbody.='Click here </a>to activate your account.</td></tr>';
                $msgbody.='</table>';
                mail($toemail,$subject,$msgbody,$from='');
```